# Using a 'where' statement in Linq only when a variable has a value

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a linq query that is creating a list.  I only want to use the second `where` clause if `affiliationID != 0`.  Any tips?

```
var associations = (from a in ftjent.Associations
                    join ap in ftjent.AssociationProducts on a.AssociationID equals ap.AssociationID
                    where ap.Product.Name == productName
                    where a.AffiliationID == affiliationID
                    select new
                        {
                            a.Acronym,
                            a.AssociationID,
                            a.Name
                         }
                     ).Distinct().OrderBy(assoc => assoc.Acronym);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare `affiliationId` with 0, if it does not have a value the `where` will always evaluate to `true` and the second comparison will not be made:

```
var associations = (from a in ftjent.Associations
                join ap in ftjent.AssociationProducts on a.AssociationID equals ap.AssociationID
                where ap.Product.Name == productName
                where (affiliationId == 0) ||  a.AffiliationID == affiliationID
                select new
                    {
                        a.Acronym,
                        a.AssociationID,
                        a.Name
                     }
                 ).Distinct().OrderBy(assoc => assoc.Acronym);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var associations = (from a in ftjent.Associations
                join ap in ftjent.AssociationProducts on a.AssociationID equals ap.AssociationID
                where ap.Product.Name == productName
                && (a.AffiliationID == affiliationID
                   || affiliationID == null || affiliationID == 0)
                select new
                    {
                        a.Acronym,
                        a.AssociationID,
                        a.Name
                     }
                 ).Distinct().OrderBy(assoc => assoc.Acronym);
```

Basically, instead of trying to only append the condition under a condition, the usual solution to these types of problems (which are common, believe me) is to give the negative of the condition as an "or", giving the query an alternate; here, either the record's affiliationID must match the criteria, or the criteria value isn't meaningful, and so the full condition is true for ALL records.

Answer (score 0):

Another option too:

```
var associations = (from a in ftjent.Associations
                join ap in ftjent.AssociationProducts on a.AssociationID equals   ap.AssociationID
                where ap.Product.Name == productName               
                select new
                    {
                        a.Acronym,
                        a.AssociationID,
                        a.Name,
                        a.AffiliationID //add AffilationID into the unknown type

                     }
                 ).Distinct().OrderBy(assoc => assoc.Acronym);

if(affilationID != 0)
     associations = associations.Where(a=>a.AffiliationID == affiliationID);
```

This is not the shortest code, but it makes clear separation of flow.

Choice is your.

Comment: While I agree conceptually, in practice this could error if the source collections are Queryables, and the query provider can't handle multiple Where() calls in the Expression tree.

Comment: @KeithS: this is just another *possible* solution. As I wrote, the choice is up to the OP's.

Answer (score -1):

It's prety hard to do it using the query comprehension syntax like you have, but you can always pull out the logic and make another IQueryable before doing the query using the query comprehension syntax.

```
var products = ftjent.AssociationProducts;
if (affiliationID != null)
    products = products.Where(x => x.AffiliationID = affiliationID);

var associations = (
    from a in ftjent.Associations
    join ap in products on a.AssociationID equals ap.AssociationID
    where ap.Product.Name == productName
    select new
    {
        a.Acronym,
        a.AssociationID,
        a.Name
    }
)
.Distinct()
.OrderBy(assoc => assoc.Acronym);
```

Comment: In fact, it is near-trivial to conditionally evaluate a condition within a single query. See devundef's and my answers. In addition, in the OP it's Association, not AssociationProduct, that has the AffiliationID.

Comment: Well, if you are using Linq-to-Entities or Linq-to-SQL, your query is going to be sub-optimal and not use indexes with your OR condition.